# Why am I getting "No virtual folder, aborting" when I try to tag messages in Mutt?

Tags: mutt

I've been using the <kbd>`</kbd> to open the tag prompt in `mutt-kz`. That was working this morning. Now, though, when I type <kbd>`</kbd> I'm seeing

```
No virtual folder, aborting.
```

I'm not sure what this might be about or how I brought it on. Any leads welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm repeating what I said on the github issue, you are probably not in a virtual folder when you attempt to tag.  Tagging works only in a virtual folder, so it will fail in `=INBOX` but will succeed in `tag:inbox`.

Comment: The [Mutt manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/manual/) does not contain the phrase "virtual folder". What do you mean by a virtual folder?

Comment: @sampablokuper The question was about a fork of mutt, with integrated `notmuch` support.  This fork has now been merged into the [Neomutt project](https://neomutt.org/).

Answer (score 0):

As Suvayu said, probably you are not in a Virtual Folder. I was having a similar problem but because when I was changing folder with a shortcut, I was using "=", which, even if you use "change-vfolder", takes you to a normal folder. For example:

macro index,pager i "=inbox" #Takes you to the normal inbox

While if you write without the "=" it goes to the Virtual Folder:

macro index,pager i "Inbox" #"Go to the virtual  Inbox"